# Charts and Object Type Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

New to the Chart Service and was hoping to elaborate more on this post [Google charts object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132295/google-charts-object-error)

I'm running into the same "object type does not match column type"  problem, but I've checked the rows and made sure the data was the same type.  If I set the whole sheet as format plain text, the graphs execute correctly and no errors; but I loose all the filters and functions that use dates of flights or try to sum flight time, and count flight types on other sheets in the workbook.

Is there a way to have the charts string the column data before using it? (simply).  I even set the data range to not include the string headers just in case that was the issue, that didn't work either.

Link to sample data sheet:[Sample Data Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvmOEVr803HMdGNLXzBxNVYwTFAwZjRwYWlPWm5oYUE#gid=0)

Here is the code:

```
      function doGet(){
    //Get the data from spreadsheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('hoistLog'));
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Flight Tracking');
    var data = sheet.getDataRange();

    //Filters
    var unitFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
    .setFilterColumnIndex(22)
    .build();

    var missionTypeFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
    .setFilterColumnIndex(2)
    .build();

    //Charts
    var missionTypePieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
    .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([2]))
    .setDimensions(550, 350)
    .setTitle('Mission Types')
    .set3D()
    .build();

    var unitTypePieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
    .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([22]))
    .setDimensions(550, 350)
    .setTitle('Flights By Unit')
    .set3D()
    .build();

    var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
    .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0, 2, 22, 23, 24, 25,     33, 34, 35, 36, 37]))
    .setDimensions(1100, 500)
    .build();

    //Dasboard
    var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
    .bind([unitFilter, missionTypeFilter], [missionTypePieChart, unitTypePieChart,   tableChart])
    .build();

    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var filterPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
    var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
    var tablePanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
    filterPanel.add(unitFilter).add(missionTypeFilter).setSpacing(10);
    chartPanel.add(missionTypePieChart).add(unitTypePieChart).setSpacing(10);
    tablePanel.add(tableChart).setSpacing(10);

                        dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel).add(tablePanel));
    app.add(dashboard);
    return app;  
   }
```

Thanks Ahead of time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the line `var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)`, data is a range here. You need to convert it somehow like that:

```
//Dasboard
var vals=data.getValues();
var dataTable=Charts.newDataTable();
for (var i in vals[0]) {
  dataTable.addColumn (Charts.ColumnType.STRING, ""+i);
}
for (var i in vals) {
  var x=vals[i];
  for (var j in x) {
    x[j]=""+x[j];
  }  
  dataTable.addRow (vals[i]);
}  
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(dataTable)
.bind([unitFilter, missionTypeFilter], [missionTypePieChart, unitTypePieChart,   tableChart])
.build();
```

Then it will display something. However, the conversion can be adopted to fit your table more (here everything is just converted to a string, and the headers are just 0, 1, 2...)

Answer (score 0):

I found that even on a newly created spreadsheet with data added :

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange();
```

was not working.

I instead named the range and specified it by name to limit the data range to the data entered:

```
var data = ss.getRangeByName("theData");
```

It seems to be finding something outside the intended data range that I thought `.getDataRange` would limit to.

Answer (score 0):

If date columns contain some blanks in your sheet, open the sheet and format those columns as "Number > Plain Text" to prevent the error "object type does not match column type".