# Creating Bar Chart - Adding Rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am trying to create a bar chart from a google spreadsheet. I do not want to manually add each column and row so it seems that this example should work and automate that process with the for loop.

The example below is from https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/chart-services/bar-chart

The error shows "Row has too many cells. Should be at most as the columns number."

```
function doGet(){
  //Get the data from spreadsheet
  ssID ='SpreadsheetID';//Change it to yours
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssID');
  var sheet = SS.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getRange('A1:G7').getValues();

  //Build data table
  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();

  //Add Column types
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, data[0][0]);
  for(var i=1; i<data[0].length-1; i++){
    dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, data[0][i]);
  }

  //Add rows
  for(var j=1; j<data.length; j++){
    dataTable.addRow(data[j]);
    Logger.log(data[j])
  }

  //Create and build chart
  var chart = Charts.newBarChart()
      .setDataTable(dataTable)
      .setTitle("Sales by store")
      .build();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("AST Chart");
  app.add(chart)
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've selected a range `'A1:G7'`. That's 7 columns by 7 rows. Now, you start building your dataTable by adding columns.

1: `dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, data[0][0]);`

2-6: `for(var i=1; i<data[0].length-1; i++)`

See, `data[0].length` is equal to `7`, and the loop goes through `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, all numbers less than `6`.

Then when you start adding data rows, there aren't enough columns in the dataTable, and you get the error you've seen. (It is pretty clear now, isn't it?)

To fix it, change your loop upper bound.

```
//Add Column types
dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, data[0][0]);
for(var i=1; i<data[0].length; i++) {
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,data[0][i]);
}
```

... or loop over all columns, making type decisions inside the loop...

```
//Add Column types
for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
    dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING,data[0][i]);
  }
  else {
    dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,data[0][i]);
  }
}
```

... or same thing, but using the ternary operator to reduce the code...

```
//Add Column types
for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){
  dataTable.addColumn(
     i==0 ? Charts.ColumnType.STRING : Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER,
     data[0][i]);
}
```

There are many other ways you could do this, but whichever you choose, just make sure you cover the full range of values that you need to.

Comment: Thanks. Now for some reason when I try to use DATE as the ColumnType, it will give an error "Object does not match the ColumnType." The data is in date format on sheets. If I have the data in Plain text, it will work, but not if I have it as date format.

Comment: ALL data in the column must be the same type, and must match the column type you've specified. Blanks are interpreted as Strings. More about that in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132295) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712644).

Comment: The columns are filled with no blanks and designated as DATE. Still wont take it.